# SetSuspendState() hangs up, why?

Tags: c++, winapi, sleep, freeze, logoff

I was wondering why the following happens?

I need to log off users and then put computer to sleep. I do the following (C++/WinAPI):

(Calling the following from the local system service):

```
WTSLogoffSession(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, dwUserSessionID, TRUE);
SetSuspendState(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE);
```

But when I run this code on Windows Vista, SetSuspendState() hangs up and never returns. At the same time the system does not enter sleep mode either.

Comment: Does your process have `SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME` privilege?

Comment: Yes. But even if it doesn't the SetSuspendState shouldn't hang up, should it?